# Python print a list of two element in one line in a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

i have a list as:

```
one = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
for o in one:
    print o
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
```

i need to print (1, 2) and (3, 4) in the same line

```
for o in one:
    print o
(1, 2) (3, 4)
```

Comment: `print o,` will do that

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but it has the solution to this problem.

Comment: @thefourtheye good enough I think. The answer can be found by googling for 3 seconds anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python2, it would be done as follows:

```
one = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
for o in one:
    print o,      #added the ,
print      #and an optional print() to ensure that anything afterwords prints on a separate line
```

In python3, you need slight modifications since `print` becomes a function:

```
one = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
for o in one:
    print(o, end=' ')
print()    #and an optional print() to ensure that anything afterwords prints on a separate line
```

Alternatively (thanks to @user2357112 for the suggestion)

```
one = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
print(*one)

[OUTPUT]  from all
(1, 2)(3, 4)
```

Comment: The Python 3 example doesn't work, due to the removal of the confusing soft-space feature. See the output, with missing space: http://ideone.com/S5bErt

Comment: @user2357112, Do you mean that there is no space in between?

Comment: Yes. I recommend `print(*one)`, with no loop.

Comment: @user2357112, Thank you very much. I have included that in my answer.

Comment: Also, the `print o,` and `print(o, end='')` versions may need an extra `print` at the end to get a newline, so the next thing you want to print doesn't show up on the same line too.